# strstr() function like, that ignores upper or lower case

Tags: c, string

I have two strings. Lets say `

```
str1="One Two Three";
```

and

```
str2="two";
```

I would like to know if there is any function that checks for a match of the second string in the first one,and returns me a pointer to the first occurrence, something like `strstr()`, but which doesn't treat the same letter, upper or lowercase, as two different characters.

For my example, the function should find a match for `str2` in the first string, despite the uppercase `"T"`, of `"Two"`.

Comment: Why don't you just convert them both to lower/upper case and then compare them?

Comment: What code do you have so far? What programming language are you using?

Comment: There isn't a `stristr()` C library function, but you could make one for yourself...

Comment: I thought about that,but I am not allowed to modify the str1 with the exception of removing the given string that is found.I have to keep from str1 just"One Three" as they are here and if I make all the letters in lowercase or uppercase it would modify the result.

Comment: Make copies of the strings.

Comment: @WeatherVane that would scale extremely poorly.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From the manpage for `strstr`:

```
STRSTR(3)           Linux Programmer's Manual           STRSTR(3)

NAME
       strstr, strcasestr - locate a substring

SYNOPSIS
       #include <string.h>

       char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);

       #define _GNU_SOURCE

       #include <string.h>

       char *strcasestr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);

DESCRIPTION
       The  strstr()  function  finds the first occurrence of the substring needle in
       the string haystack.  The terminating '\0' characters are not compared.

       The strcasestr() function is like strstr(3), but  ignores  the  case  of  both
       arguments.

RETURN VALUE
       These functions return a pointer to the beginning of the substring, or NULL if
       the substring is not found.
```

So what you're looking for is `strcasestr`.

Comment: My man page says, "The strstr() function conforms to C89 and C99.  The strcasestr() function is a non-standard extension."

Comment: It's not in my Visual C library.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't though about searching in the man...Next time I will start with that. :D

Comment: @FredLarson : It is not an ISO C library function, it is part of the GNU C library.  Microsoft's case-insensitive functions use `i` rather than `case` (e.g. `stricmp()`), but does not define a `stristr()`.

Comment: @Clifford: Yup, that's a non-standard extension for you.

Answer (score 14):

If you're on windows, you can use [StrStrI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773439(v=vs.85).aspx). It works the same as the GNU `strcasestr` or the other manually-implemented `stristr` code in other answers here.

E.g.:

```
const char needle[] = "and";
const char haystack[] = "me and you";

const char* pAnd = StrStrIA(haystack, needle); // explicitly call ascii version as windows defaults to wchar
printf("%s\n", pAnd); // Prints "and you";
```

Answer (score 13):

While some compiler's C libraries include extensions with case insensitive versions of the standard string functions, such as GNU's `strcasestr()`, the naming of such functions is not standardised even when included.

One way of overcoming the lack of a standard implementation is of course to implement your own:

```
char* stristr( const char* str1, const char* str2 )
{
    const char* p1 = str1 ;
    const char* p2 = str2 ;
    const char* r = *p2 == 0 ? str1 : 0 ;

    while( *p1 != 0 && *p2 != 0 )
    {
        if( tolower( (unsigned char)*p1 ) == tolower( (unsigned char)*p2 ) )
        {
            if( r == 0 )
            {
                r = p1 ;
            }

            p2++ ;
        }
        else
        {
            p2 = str2 ;
            if( r != 0 )
            {
                p1 = r + 1 ;
            }

            if( tolower( (unsigned char)*p1 ) == tolower( (unsigned char)*p2 ) )
            {
                r = p1 ;
                p2++ ;
            }
            else
            {
                r = 0 ;
            }
        }

        p1++ ;
    }

    return *p2 == 0 ? (char*)r : 0 ;
}
```

The test code below outputs:

```
Two Three
Two Three
NULL
cdefg
CDEFG
CdEfG
NULL
zzzz
NULL

zzzzz
NULL
```

---

```
int main(void) 
{
    char* test = stristr( "One TTwo Three", "two" ) ;
    printf( "%s\n", test == 0 ? "NULL" : test  ) ;

    test = stristr( "One Two Three", "two" ) ;
    printf( "%s\n", test == 0 ? "NULL" : test  ) ;

    test = stristr( "One wot Three", "two" ) ;
    printf( "%s\n", test == 0 ? "NULL" : test  ) ;

    test = stristr( "abcdefg", "cde" ) ;
    printf( "%s\n", test == 0 ? "NULL" : test  ) ;

    test = stristr( "ABCDEFG", "cde" ) ;
    printf( "%s\n", test == 0 ? "NULL" : test  ) ;

    test = stristr( "AbCdEfG", "cde" ) ;
    printf( "%s\n", test == 0 ? "NULL" : test  ) ;

    test = stristr( "1234567", "cde" ) ;
    printf( "%s\n", test == 0 ? "NULL" : test  ) ;

    test = stristr( "zzzz", "zz" ) ;
    printf( "%s\n", test == 0 ? "NULL" : test  ) ;

    test = stristr( "zz", "zzzzz" ) ;
    printf( "%s\n", test == 0 ? "NULL" : test  ) ;

    test = stristr( "", "" ) ;
    printf( "%s\n", test == 0 ? "NULL" : test  ) ;

    test = stristr( "zzzzz", "" ) ;
    printf( "%s\n", test == 0 ? "NULL" : test  ) ;

    test = stristr( "", "zzzz" ) ;
    printf( "%s\n", test == 0 ? "NULL" : test  ) ;

    test = stristr("AAABCDX","AABC") ;
    printf( "%s\n", test == 0 ? "NULL" : test  ) ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I too got caught in corner cases trying to act like `strstr("","zz"), strstr("zz", ""), strstr("","")`.

Comment: Corrected `"",""` and `"zzzz", ""` test cases - both return `str1` as per standard `strstr()`.

Comment: It fails with `stristr("AAABCDX","AABC")`

Comment: @BernardoRamos : Thanks - fixed it.  `p1` is now reset to the character immediately following the initial match (`r + 1`) when a mismatch is detected.  Added test case.  Now also const-correct.

Comment: `tolower(*p1)` may pass negative values to `tolower()` is type `char` is signed by default, which is very common.  You should cast the argument this way: `tolower((unsigned char)*p1)`.  The same for all instances and all functions from `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: @chqrlie : It is a potential gotcha, but for ASCII characters (<=127) this would never be a problem, and the implicit cast is safe.  Given the poorly defined and locale specific behaviour for characters > 127, I would not trust consistent behaviour across platforms for such characters in any event.

Comment: @Clifford: the problem is simple: there is potential undefined behavior if `char` is signed and the string contains characters < 0. The fix is simple: use `tolower((unsigned char)*p1)`. It is unfortunate that `char` can be signed, which is inconsistent with the behavior of `getc()` and `strcmp()` but this historical choice cannot be changed, yet its consequences for the `<ctype.h>` functions can be prevented. In my country, it is fairly common for strings to contain non-ASCII characters, undefined behavior should be avoided even if locale specific behavior is not perfect.

Comment: @chqrlie ; Yes; I don't dispute that.  Feel free to modify my post.  It is too old for _me_ to care enough.

Answer (score 7):

After accept answer

Inspired by [@Clifford](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27304609/2410359) and [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27303852/2410359), thought I'd try rolling up a solution that only used standard library functions.

```
char* stristr3(const char* haystack, const char* needle) {
  do {
    const char* h = haystack;
    const char* n = needle;
    while (tolower((unsigned char) *h) == tolower((unsigned char ) *n) && *n) {
      h++;
      n++;
    }
    if (*n == 0) {
      return (char *) haystack;
    }
  } while (*haystack++);
  return 0;
}
```

Somewhat tricky to match the corner cases of `strstr()` with inputs like `"x",""`, `"","x"`, `"",""`

Comment: Nice - I have corrected mine to produce the same output as yours. Yours is somewhat more succinct perhaps. The casts are unnecessary (`tolower()` takes an `int` - passing a char is safe, and normal), and the signature of strstr() in C is `char* strstr( char*, const char* )`, so the cast in the return would not be necessary if you use that.

Comment: @Clifford C11 7.4 Character handling says "the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined"  So if `char` is signed and `ch < 0`, then passing it to `tolower(ch)` results in `ch` remaining a negative number and not getting mapped in to the `unsigned char` range - thus UB.  By first casting, `(unsigned char) ch`, code insures a non-negative value is passed to `tolower()`.

Comment: I wondered about the necessity of an unsigned char, as letters are all below the ASCII value 128. Then I tried it with "Über" and "über" and it doesn't work anyway, because unlike the English upper/lowercase alphabet, the ASCII values 129 and 154 are not 32 apart.

Comment: @Clifford In C11dr 7.24.5.7 The strstr function: has  `char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);`, `s1` is `const`.

Comment: @Weather Vane When `char` values are non-ASCII (0-127), all sorts of issues come into play.  When you said "I tried it with "Über" and "über" and it doesn't work anyway", what is "it"?

Comment: @chux "It" was "none of the `stristr()` solutions posted". Just curious as to how the library functions handle umlauted letters.

Comment: @Weather Vane To well handle "Über" and "über", the character code page and matching `setlocale()` are needed.  BTW, my Üü values differ and are 32 apart.  C frankly is weak in this area and I suspect UTF8 will take over eventually rendering all single `char` code like this obsolete.

Comment: @chux Thanks, yes, I haven't explored that or Unicode or wide char coding. As it happens the umlauted letters I used copied properly from the text editor where I compose, into the pasted SO comment.

Comment: @chux: UV'd, but I was unhappy with the `do / while` loop, so I came up with a more efficient version, albeit one line longer ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a slightly more efficient version, that does not call `tolower()` twice per character in the `haystack` string:

```
#include <ctype.h>

char *stristr4(const char *haystack, const char *needle) {
    int c = tolower((unsigned char)*needle);
    if (c == '\0')
        return (char *)haystack;
    for (; *haystack; haystack++) {
        if (tolower((unsigned char)*haystack) == c) {
            for (size_t i = 0;;) {
                if (needle[++i] == '\0')
                    return (char *)haystack;
                if (tolower((unsigned char)haystack[i]) != tolower((unsigned char)needle[i]))
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: The O() for this and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27305359/2410359) are both `O(h_len * n_len)` A truly more efficient would use a `O(h_len + n_len)` approach.

Comment: @chux: I agree, and I wrote *slightly more efficient*. Alternative versions with **O(h_len + n_len)** has a setup cost that makes it slower in most cases.  **O(h_len * n_len)** is a worst case happening only for pathological argument strings.

Comment: My tests indicate this is measurably faster, (and same functionality).

Comment: What I found most interesting was that pre-populating a `int tl[256]` with `tolower()` values, prior to testing sped things up 4x.

Comment: @chux: how many tests do you run? pre-populating an array with `tolower()` values will load the ctype tables into the cache, but this should only impact timings for the few initial cases.  `tolower()` is affected by your current locale settings in non-trivial ways.

Comment: Many configurations with 10000 patterns 10000 times each.  I agree "should only impact timings for the few initial cases" - but it did not.  IAC, Your nice answer and  mine tracked proportionally.  Significant O() improvement needs a different approach.

Comment: @chux: This is intriguing! did you do anything else when pre-populating this array, such as setting the locale?  It might be worth asking as a separate question...

Comment: I will consider - but now its the week-end.

Answer (score 2):

Implementation of `stristr()`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char *stristr (const char *str, const char *strSearch) {
    char *sors, *subs, *res = NULL;
    if ((sors = strdup (str)) != NULL) {
        if ((subs = strdup (strSearch)) != NULL) {
            res = strstr (strlwr (sors), strlwr (subs));
            if (res != NULL)
                res = str + (res - sors);
            free (subs);
        }
        free (sors);
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    char *str1 = "One Two Three";
    char *str2 = "two";
    char *sptr = stristr(str1, str2);
    if (sptr)
        printf ("Substring is at index %d\n", sptr - str1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A somewhat "expensive" implementation.

Comment: This is a complete implementation, +1 for that.  Since it is meant for a system that does not all ready have it, it also makes sense to implement it with only standard C functions and not depend on other functions that the system may also not have like `strdup()` and `strlwr()`.

Comment: Thanks... could write `strdup()` and `strlwr()` too ;-)

Comment: I tested the performance of the three implementations given (so far) with the input `"One TTwo Three", "two"`, for 100000 calls.  Obviously platforms vary so these are comparative:  Mine: 15 ms, @chux: 16ms, yours: 172ms. However when I prefixed `str1` with 94 non-matching characters, the results were 250ms, 125ms, 218ms respectively, so yours is least sensitive to input variation, chux has the highest performance in all cases, and mine sucks at scalability!

Comment: @Clifford I had thought to solve it on a char-by-char basis as you and @chux did, but I went for the most `easy` and `understandable` way to implement.

Comment: I agree - we both had trouble getting the implementations correct, you got work done quicker!  Another interesting note on performance, running with compiler optimisation yielded 0.78ms, 0.63ms and 87.5ms respectively.  The thing about library code, is that it is already optimised and you cannot make it any faster, so yours is less affected by optimisation.  You'd have to be processing a lot of data to care perhaps.

Comment: It wasn't my problem :-)

Comment: @Clifford & Weather Vane I wonder about the result one may get should we use to upper rather than lower as I suspect it may differ once non-AZ letters used.  I have experienced a porting problem with stricmp() where one OS went for toupper and another went tolower.  Messed up sorting when `'_'` was involved.

Comment: @chux interesting confusion there, perhaps the uppercase of `_` should be... oops can't type an `upperscore`. The lesson could be to deal with casing first, locally.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this without writing any function may be by first converting both the string to lowercase/uppercase using "tolower"/"toupper" and then use "strstr" :)

Comment: But the conversion to upper/lower case is best done in a function - so you will have written a function.  What's wrong with writing a function anyway?

Comment: yeah.. I was talking about the standard library.. as it is already optimized.

Comment: Converting the strings is an unnecessary overhead - you first have to duplicate them, so the library optimisation becomes irrelevant.  Your suggestion is exactly the solution suggested by Weather Vane, and I did some performance analysis on that and added results in the comments.  Either way it is not a simple one-liner, so you would still be better off _writing a function_ as in Weather Vane's answer.  The C string library (and any extensions) may indeed be optimised, but C string handling is fundamentally inefficient and `strdup()` is particularly expensive.

Comment: You could maybe take advantage of the fact that a lowercase char is 32 (decimal) higher than  the same letter in uppercase.  So given the correct bitmask they're the same. There's 1 bit different, this comes from when ASCII progressed from all uppercase to having lowercase as well.  Teletypes from the 60s are all uppercase for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `function` :

```
char* stristr(const char* String, const char* Pattern)
{
      char *pptr, *sptr, *start;

      for (start = (char *)String; *start; start++)
      {
            /* find start of pattern in string */
            for ( ; (*start && (toupper(*start) != toupper(*Pattern))); start++)
                  ;
            if (!*start)
                  return 0;

            pptr = (char*)Pattern;
            sptr = (char*)start;

            while (toupper(*sptr) == toupper(*pptr))
            {
                  sptr++;
                  pptr++;
                  /* if end of pattern then pattern was found */
                  if (!*pptr)
                        return (start);
            }
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: The function should return `String` if `Pattern` is an empty string.